# Sending "AutomationElement" from C++ (IUIAutomationElement) to C# (AutomationElement)

Tags: c#, c++, windows, ui-automation

I've a listener in C++ which monitors for window messages and gets the `HWND` of the newly created windows. Using UIAutomation SDK for C++, I am able to get the AutomationElement and associated information from it

```
    if (pUIAutomation) {
        IUIAutomationElement *e = nullptr;
        auto hr = pUIAutomation->ElementFromHandle(hwnd, &e);
    }
```

`pUIAutomation` is pointer of type `IUIAutomation` obtained by calling `CoCreateInstance`.

Is there a way to pass this `IUIAutomationElement *` to C# `AutomationElement`? There is a c# module where further processing needs to be done.

I am aware that C# itself can directly listen to events and get the `AutomationElement` of new windows, but I can't use it. Also, `hwnd` can be passed to C# module and `AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd)` can be used to get it.

I am looking if I can directly pass the automation element itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need the IRawElementProviderSimple interface pointer so you can use AutomationElement.FromLocalProvider on the C# side.  It is not obvious to me how you get one from an IUIAutomationElement, try QueryInterface().  Odds don't look that good to me, smells like this could work in the provider but not the client.

Comment: @HansPassant  Thanks. As suggested, I've tried getting that `IRawElementProviderSimple`, got error from `QueryInterface` with `E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported.`